# Is there any way to customize the style of Twitter @Anywhere

Tags: jquery, twitter

I have @Anywhere working and the tweetBox is showing up and I have a lot of it customized with the following code. I am curious if there is anyway to customize the tweet button including changing its location, using an image instead, etc.

```
twttr.anywhere(function (t) { 
  var me = this; 
  var a = t('#tweetControls').tweetBox({
   height : 75, 
   width : 480, 
   defaultContent : 'Default Text', 
   counter : false, 
   label : '&nbsp;', 
   complete : function (tweetBox) {
      me.tweetBox = tweetBox; 
      try {
         me.tweetBox.$editor.css({
            resize : 'none', 
            color : '#9B9B9B', 
            'font-family': 'Arial', 
            'font-size': '14px', 
            background : 'transparent', 
            'border-radius': 0, 
            '-webkit-border-radius': 0, 
            '-moz-border-radius': 0 
         }); 
         me.tweetBox.$button.css( {
            cursor : 'hand', 
            cursor : 'pointer' ,
            display: none
         }); 
    } catch (e) {
    //
    }
}, 
    onTweet : function () {
    me.tweetBox.setContent('Restore default text'); 
}
}); 
});
```

Comment: @Anywhere [is going away](https://dev.twitter.com/blog/sunsetting-anywhere).

Comment: Yup, in 4 months... if you have a better way of doing this that is client side, then I would love to see it. Been searching for a while.

Comment: You may wish to look into [the Tweet Button](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button) if you haven't already.

Comment: That kind of obviates the functionality. The hope is to have a textbox on your site that a user enters which then is submitted to Twitter after being authenticated. With the tweet button, you get a popup that you can populate, but appearance-wise you get two pop ups in a row.